# static_cast/dynamic_cast: Does it change the object?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I have some doubts about `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` in C++. Do they *completely* change the object a pointer is pointing to from a class `A` to a class `B` by preserving the already-set member variables (except the ones that cannot be passed from derived to base) ?

I noticed that if I have something like

```
struct Base
{
    Base() { }
    virtual ~Base() { }
    virtual void Method() { cout << "Base Method"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void Method() { cout << "Override Method"; }
};

struct Derived2 : public Derived
{
    Derived2() { cout << "Derived2 constructor"; }
    void Method() { cout << "Override2 Method"; }
};

int main()
{       
    Base *myPointer = new Derived();    
    static_cast<Derived2*>(myPointer)->Derived2::Method();   
    delete myPointer;    
    return 0;
}
```

The constructor isn't called, but the method does. How is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The casts don't change the object at all. They only give you a different *pointer* to a related class type in the inheritance hierarchy:

```
Derived x;

Base         * p = &x;
AnotherClass * q = dynamic_cast<AnotherClass*>(p);

// q may or may not be NULL
```

For example, the above dynamic cast succeeds if we have a hierarchy `AnotherClass : Base` and `Derived : AnotherClass` (and `Base` is polymorphic).

A `static_cast` can usually be used when you already *know* that you have a more derived dynamic type, but happen to have only a pointer or reference to a base.

(A static cast can never be used to cast from a virtual base, in which case you *always* need `dynamic_cast`.)

Comment: So how come that a derived object calls its and the base constructor, but if I switch from a derived class to a derived from derived class the constructor isn't called?

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: I don't understand your question, though I'm confident that what you're experiencing is not related to casting. Please update your question to contain a *minimal*, *complete* example of your problem.

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: Your example is just *undefined behaviour* (i.e. a programming error). There's no accounting for it. You are only allowed a static cast if you *know* the object to be of the desired type.

Comment: @KerrekSB exactly.  static cast is for when *you* know more than the *compiler* knows, and the compiler does exactly what you said to do.  In this case, you're just getting a side effect of some pointer math that just happens to work in this case.

Comment: @JohnGardner: And more importantly I suppose the fact that the class is stateless and the member function makes no reference to the object's state... it's effectively static.